# Three tables joined but need to links ids

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I have joined three tables for a query. The problem is that is displays each class Name and then dog, but does not link the dog name to specific shows. It displays the same list of dognames in every show. I have tried to do this using a show_id in my dogs table, and linking it to the show_id in shows table.

The three tables are: shows, results, dogs.

Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['s_id'])) {
    $the_show_id = $_GET['s_id'];

    $view_query = "UPDATE shows SET show_view_count = show_view_count + 1 WHERE  show_id = $the_show_id ";
    $send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $view_query);

    if(!$send_query) {

        die("query failed" );
    }


    if(isset($_SESSION['user_role']) && $_SESSION['user_role'] == 'admin' ) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM shows WHERE show_id = $the_show_id ";

    } else {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM shows WHERE show_id = $the_show_id AND  show_status = 'published' ";
    }

    $select_all_shows_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($select_all_shows_query) < 1) {

        echo "<h1 class='text-center'>No shows available</h1>";

    } else { 

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_shows_query)) {
            $show_name = $row['show_title'];
            $show_author = $row['show_author'];
            $show_date = $row['show_date'];
            $show_content = $row['show_content'];

            ?>

            <h1 class="page-header">
                Shows
            </h1>
            <!-- First Blog Post -->
            <h2>
                <a href="#"><?php echo $show_name ?></a>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">
                by <a href="index.php"><?php echo $show_author ?></a>
            </p>
            <h4>Show Date: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span>
 <? php echo $show_date ?></h4>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><h4>Class Name</h4></div>    
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><h4>Placement</h4></div>    
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7"><h4>Dog Name</h4></div>    
            </div><hr>
            <?php  

            $query = "SELECT result.class_name, result.placement, dogs.dog_name 
            FROM result 
            INNER JOIN dogs on result.resultID = dogs.resultIDD
            INNER JOIN shows on dogs.show_id = shows.show_id
            WHERE dog_name NOT LIKE 'absent' GROUP BY shows.show_id";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

            if($result) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $dog_name = $row['dog_name'];
                    $placement = $row['placement'];
                    $class_name = $row['class_name'];
                    ?> 

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><p><?php echo $class_name ?></p></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><p><?php echo $placement ?></p></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7"><p><?php echo $dog_name ?></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: query must show error because after where condition you didn't use alias in where condition it must be like dogs.dog_name.

Comment: No error only thing that happens is each show lists all dogs not ones specific to each show

Comment: try with GROUP BY shows.show_id after where condition completes tell me what it returns ?

Comment: To test it I have inserted 4 results and 4 dogs, the query lists them but show 1 and 2 still has same results and dogs, it is not displaying each show this corresponding results and dogs?

Comment: I have included all the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming all other things are working correctly, it is possible that you need only add the dogs.show_id (or the shows.show_id either way) to the select.  Might you try the query below and then if that doesn't work report your table structure (you can use "show create table TBL_NAME" to do that for each of the three tables.

```
<?php
    $query = "
        SELECT
            dogs.show_id,
            result.class_name, result.placement,
            dogs.dog_name
        FROM
            result INNER JOIN
            dogs on result.resultID = dogs.resultIDD INNER JOIN
            shows on dogs.show_id = shows.show_id
        WHERE
            dog_name NOT LIKE 'absent'
    "; 
?>
```

UPDATE: okay, so now that we know you are already in a loop that tells us the show_id, you just need to update the query to only pull dogs for that show (assuming show_id is actually in the dogs table...which isn't really where it belongs unless you have dog+show_id as a unique, composite key).

Take a look here where i add $show_id to the list of declarations from the initial show query, and then it is used in the query to limit dogs from that query.  Also, inner join isn't best here...imho.

```
...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_shows_query)) {

  // WE ALREADY KNOW THE SHOW WE'RE IN
  $show_id = $row['show_id']; 

  $show_name = $row['show_title'];
  $show_author = $row['show_author'];
  $show_date = $row['show_date'];
  $show_content = $row['show_content'];
    ?>
      <h1 class="page-header">Shows</h1>

        <!-- First Blog Post -->
        <h2><a href="#"><?php echo $show_name ?></a></h2>
        <p class="lead"> by <a href="index.php"><?php echo $show_author ?></a></p>
        <h4>Show Date: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span> <?php echo $show_date ?></h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><h4>Class Name</h4></div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><h4>Placement</h4></div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7"><h4>Dog Name</h4></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      <?php

        // SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
        $query = "SELECT result.class_name, result.placement, dogs.dog_name
                  FROM result
                  LEFT JOIN dogs on result.resultID = dogs.resultIDD
                  WHERE dogs.show_idd = $show_id AND dog_name NOT LIKE 'absent'";

         $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error
           ("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error
           ($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

         if ($result) {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $dog_name = $row['dog_name'];
             $placement = $row['placement'];
             $class_name = $row['class_name'];
             ?>

               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><p><?php echo $class_name ?></p></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><p><?php echo $placement ?></p></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-7"><p><?php echo $dog_name ?></p></div>
               </div>
```

Comment: what is correct snytax and code to add them, should it be in the where section of the query?

Comment: Bhavin is correct if the column named `dog_name` is not unique across all tables.  @garyfalkland i have already updated the query in my answer.  were you able to test it?  To select the show_id, just add "dogs.show_id, " after "SELECT".  You will have to make use of that variable in your html, which you have not provided to us so that we may help with that portion.

Comment: $query = "SELECT dogs.show_id,  ...   are you stuck on that?

Comment: I have added the dogs.show_id but it still shows all dogs on all shows?

Comment: can you tell me what columns are in each table please?  specifically where is show_id - is that in the dog table?  is it also in the result table?

Comment: Tables are like this

Comment: These are the important ones Table:shows - show_id, show_title, show_date. Table:reults - result_ID, class-name, placement, . Table Dogs: - dog_id, dog_name, result_IDD, show_id.

Comment: I would surmise that results "belong" to a show.  I would be adding the show_id to the results table if results belong to the show.  Then if you have the result_IDD linking that result to the show, you have a proper descending heirarchy:  Show -> Result(s) -> Dog(s)

Comment: WEBjuju when i add your code i get this error: Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: SELECT result.class_name, result.placement, dogs.dog_name FROM result LEFT JOIN dogs on result.resultID = dogs.resultIDD WHERE dogs.show_id = 2 AND dog_name NOT LIKE 'absent' - Error: Unknown column 'dogs.show_id' in 'where clause' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/show.php on line 94 Call Stack: 0.0008 237344 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/show.php:0 0.0089 259136 2. trigger_error() /home/ubuntu/workspace/show.php:94

Comment: You're getting uknown column for dogs.show_id...hmm, am i misunderstanding that your **Table Dogs**: - dog_id, dog_name, result_IDD, **show_id**  (has a show_id?)

Comment: yes it has a show_id which limks to the show_id in shows table

Comment: You will have to explain this error then: **Error: Unknown column 'dogs.show_id'** in 'where clause'.  That is contradicting your response.

Comment: Would you mind running **show create table dogs** for me, please; and do post the output.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `dogs` (
 `dog_id` int(33) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dog_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `affix` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `resultIDD` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `show_idd` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`dog_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
Print

Comment: ah, the show_id column has two "d"s in it.  i'm updating my answer now.

Comment: SELECT result.class_name, result.placement, dogs.dog_name
                  FROM result
                  LEFT JOIN dogs on result.resultID = dogs.resultIDD
                  WHERE dogs.show_idd = $show_id AND dog_name NOT LIKE 'absent'

Comment: Yipee worked like a dream you are ace. Thanks really appreciated